# WPF DataGrid to BindingList not working, never shows results

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I'm trying to bind data to a DataGrid via a property and then later update that property to change(sorting) the results in the datagrid.

I initially bind the DataGrid:

```
    BindingList<Booking> tourBookings;

    private async void PageFrame_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {

            tourBookings = new BindingList<Booking>((await DataManager.BookingsRef.GetBookingHeaders(PageSize, CurrentPage)).TourBookings);

            dgBookings.DataContext = tourBookings;

    }
```

Nothing is in the DataGrid at this point, either way I have a sort method:

```
    private async void DataGrid_Sorting_1(object sender, DataGridSortingEventArgs e) {

        tourBookings = new BindingList<Booking>((await DataManager.BookingsRef.GetBookingHeaders(s, asc, PageSize, CurrentPage)).TourBookings);

    }
```

.. there are still no results in my datagrid...

**Where are my results?**

Here are my bindings too:

```
         <DataGrid x:Name="dgBookings" DataContext="{Binding Path=tourBookings}" Style="{StaticResource DataGridStyle}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" 
                      ScrollViewer.PanningMode="VerticalOnly"  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
                       ScrollViewer.PanningDeceleration="5"  ScrollViewer.PanningRatio="1" Grid.RowSpan="2"
                      Grid.Row="1" RowEditEnding="DataGrid_RowEditEnding_1"  CanUserSortColumns="True" Sorting="DataGrid_Sorting_1">

            <DataGrid.Columns>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*" SortMemberPath="Time" SortDirection="Ascending">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                        Time
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding StartTime, StringFormat=HH:mm}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*" SortMemberPath="TourID">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                        Tour ID 1
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TourID}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

 ..... and load of other properties and then close datagrid.columns etc
```

Answer (score 2):

binding just works with public properties, your tourbookings is just a field.

```
 BindingList<Booking> tourBookings {get;set;}
```

EDIT:

you have to set the itemssource

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=tourBookings}" />
```

EDIT2:

if you set the datacontext to your list, then your binding should look like this

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
```

Comment: But if I set the itemssource will the datagrid fail to update when I change the tourBookings property?

Comment: You need to implement IPropertyChanged in the ViewModel

Comment: it depends on what you mean by "change". if you change your tourbookings e.g. tourbookings = new ... then you have to call PropertyChanged("tourbookings"). if you just add/remove items to tourbookings your collection has to implement INotifyCollectionChanged e.g. ObservableCollection<Booking>